How to set up Laravel Reverb in a production with Apache server
I am working on a website which is an online game using Laravel 11 with View 3 and Reverb (SPA without SSR for now). On the localhost the websockets work, but when I uploaded it to the production server with Apache they don't work.
On localhost in .env I have
REVERB_HOST="localhost"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

In production I change them to
REVERB_HOST="www.mydomain.com"
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

Also in the virtual host file I add
<VirtualHost 192.168.100.12:443>
...
 SSLEngine On
 ProxyPass "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
 ProxyPassReverse "/app" "ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app"
</VirtualHost>

After these settings in the browser tab for Network / websockets I now get that there is a connection established
{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"325487270.879942365\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}
{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"yzvrte6lfsudidxcfwkg:4055a502db436191e71198aeadf394db1defd0850c86e55f37fde6d59a9e83eb","channel":"private-user.3"}}
{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":"{}","channel":"private-user.3"}

As well as pinging periodically. But when the server tries to send data through the websocket I get the error
The POST method is not supported for route apps/174502/events. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

This route is located in /vendor/laravel/reverb/src/Servers/Reverb/Factory.php

    protected static function pusherRoutes(): RouteCollection
    {
        $routes = new RouteCollection;
...
        $routes->add('events', Route::post('/apps/{appId}/events', new EventsController));
        return $routes;
    }


Why is it giving me this error? I might be doing something wrong in the configuration. Does anyone have any idea how to properly configure Reverb for Apache?

If you run aphp artisan route:list on apache do you see your route? Is there any other dependecies you need to install on apache? I had to cofigure Proxy modules before. Anying more useful in the error more logs? is the POST method protected by authentication? Have you tried adding something like this for debugging <Location /app>Require all granted</Location>

After struggling with this for almost 2 days, I have finally managed to get Reverb working on AWS LAMP server in production.
You need to add a few more things to your .env file

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb 
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
REVERB_SERVER=reverb
REVERB_SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
REVERB_APP_ID= replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_APP_KEY=replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_APP_SECRET=replace_with_your_keys
REVERB_HOST=yourdomain.com
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https

# if you use vite add this too, same info
VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY=replace_with_your_keys
VITE_REVERB_HOST=yourdomain.com
VITE_REVERB_PORT=443
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=https

That is all, you don't need to setup reverse proxy or open any port.

For me the correct/required Apache config was/is:
# Laravel Reverb
ProxyPass /app ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app ws://0.0.0.0:8080/app
ProxyPass /apps http://0.0.0.0:8080/apps
ProxyPassReverse /apps http://0.0.0.0:8080/apps

Note that as per documentation Reverb uses two different endpoints, /app handles websocket connections and /apps handles api requests.
